# Using JSON in a request header

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to call an api with Python where a part of the headers contain "{}".

With Curl it works directly:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'token: {"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "zh-CN" }' -d '{ \ 
   "account": "email@domain.com", \ 
   "pwd": "mypassword", \ 
   "is_local": true, \ 
   "agreement_agreement": 0 \ 
 }' 'http://globalapi.sems.com.cn:82/api/v1/Common/CrossLogin'
```

But with Python I cannot get it to work, the api throws an error. I suspect it is due to the format of the token in the header as it is a string containing {}.
See the different variants commented out below - the api accepts none of them.
It works fine to use {} in a dict with Python just using regular code:

```
sems_headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'text/json',
    'token': '{"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "en-GB"}' 
}
for c, d in sems_headers.items():
    print(c, d)
```

**How can I call the api with the format required of the token in Python?**

```
sems_headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'text/json',
    #'token': "'uid':'email@domain.com', 'timestamp':'0', 'token':'', 'client':'web', 'version':'', 'language':'en-GB'" 
    #'token': '{"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "en-GB"}' 
    #'token': ''{{"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "en-GB"}}' 
    #'token': "{""uid"": ""email@domain.com"", ""timestamp"": 0, ""token"": "" "", ""client"": ""web"", ""version"": "" "", ""language"": ""en-GB"" }"
}

sems_post_data = {
    'account':'email@domain.com',
    'pwd':'mypassword',
    'is_local':True,
    'agreement_agreement':0
}

post = requests.post("https://globalapi.sems.com.cn/api/v1/Common/CrossLogin", headers=sems_headers, data=sems_post_data)

print(post.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried using an actual `dict` rather than putting it in a string? As in `'token': {'uid': 'email@domain.com', 'timestamp': '0' ...so on}`

Comment: Also can you include a copy/paste of the specific error you're encountering so we can best help you?

Comment: @awarrier99 Using a ``dict`` as ``token`` is invalid. Header values "must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'dict'>".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yup just found that in the docs. @herrbert ignore my original suggestion of using an actual `dict`, but please do include the error so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is correct.

Below can refer - 
https://iot-guider.com/raspberrypi/making-post-http-requests-with-python-flask/

Comment: have you tried with `'token': json.dumps({"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "en-GB"})`. Anything in the header should be a string, so you need to dump your JSON dictionary into a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the requests docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) it looks like your issue may actually be with how you're sending your JSON payload, as the data keyword argument sends form-encoded data rather than JSON-encoded. Try either explicitly JSON-encoding your payload, or using the json keyword argument instead:

`post = requests.post("https://globalapi.sems.com.cn/api/v1/Common/CrossLogin", headers=sems_headers, json=sems_post_data)`

or

```
import json
post = requests.post("https://globalapi.sems.com.cn/api/v1/Common/CrossLogin", headers=sems_headers, data=json.dumps(sems_post_data))
```

Also your `Accept` header should be changed to `application/json` and in order to parse the JSON response content, you should use `post.json()` rather than `post.text`

Altogether this would be:

```
sems_headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'token': '{"uid": "email@domain.com","timestamp": 0,"token": "","client": "web","version": "","language": "en-GB"}' 
}

sems_post_data = {
    'account':'email@domain.com',
    'pwd':'mypassword',
    'is_local':True,
    'agreement_agreement':0
}

post = requests.post("https://globalapi.sems.com.cn/api/v1/Common/CrossLogin", headers=sems_headers, json=sems_post_data)

print(post.json())
```

Comment: thanks, adding json-dumps for the data in the request solved it!

Comment: @herrbert awesome, no problem